# Python error - sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, openssl

Doesn't works in `Python` but works in `NodeJS`

Python code

```py
import requests

certificado_pem = './ENBPAREquipamentoCCEEA1.pem'
chave_privada = './chave_privada.key'

url = "https://servicos.ccee.org.br:443/ws/v2/RelatorioBSv2"
payload = "..."

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'text/xml; charset=utf-8',
    'SOAPAction': 'listarRelatorio'
}

response = requests.post(
    url,
    headers=headers,
    data=payload,
    cert=(certificado_pem, chave_privada),
    verify=False  # Se você quiser verificar o certificado do servidor
)

print(response.text)
```

Output error:

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ruannawe/projects/others/certs/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    response = requests.post(
  File "/home/ruannawe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 115, in post
    return request("post", url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ruannawe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ruannawe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/ruannawe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 703, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ruannawe/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='servicos.ccee.org.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ws/v2/RelatorioBSv2 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

Did I miss any settings in Python code?

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.